# Conditional formatting, the difference in values in A and B greater than 2.5

Tags: excel

I have values in A1 and B1 , C1 and D1 and so on and they are all paired.
How do i highlight the cells if the difference between the two cells are more than 2.5? Values in A1 can be smaller than B1

[image: Data sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to work out a general formula for this, not as easy as I thought.

Assuming the data starts in column B,

```
=OR(AND(ISEVEN(COLUMN(B1)),ABS(C1-B1)>2.5),AND(ISODD(COLUMN(B1)),ABS(A1-B1)>2.5))
```

applied to all of the data.

What if the first column is column A? The second part of the formula wouldn't work (because you can't reference the column before column 1) so I ended up with the rather ugly

```
=OR(AND(ISODD(COLUMN(A1)),ABS(A1-B1)>2.5),AND(ISEVEN(COLUMN(A1)),ABS(INDEX(1:1,COLUMN(A1))-INDEX(1:1,MAX(COLUMN(A1)-1,1)))>2.5))
```

Comment: Nice bit of arcane knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Highlight your cells:
1) Click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule
2) Click on Use a formula to determine which cells to format. 
3) Format values where this formula is true = ABS(A1-B1) > 2.5
4) Click Format and choose the color fill you want 
5) Click okay.

Note: you need to do for each paired column and replace the Cell Reference in Step 3)